# Wicket Ajax request causes Access Denied

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I am currently having some trouble with a Wicket project using AJAX.

The problem occurs on a `WebPage` which has a `Panel`-component that it updates with AJAX.
Within that `Panel` is a table that also uses an `AjaxPagingNavigator`.
On certain actions, the page alters a `Model` that the Panel stores which in turn is supposed to be used to update the table with AJAX.

This works fine in Development mode, but as soon as I switch the application to Deployment, the table is no longer updated, and if I try and then use the Paging Navigator, I am presented with an "Access Denied" page after I see the table being built for a moment.
I actually do not have any special Authorization Settings enabled.

If I use the Paging Navigator alone it works fine, only the cross-component request seems to be causing issues.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

EDIT: The Panel itself is added like

```
    listPanel = new DBListPanel("dbList", selectionModel /*this is a simple Model<String> that decides where the panel receives its data from in the DB*/);
    add(listPanel);
```

And a bit further down is the actual `AjaxButton` making the call:

```
    Form<String> selectDB = new Form<String>("selectDB");
    add(selectDB);

    selectDB.add(new AjaxButton("submit", selectDB) {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            listPanel.selectionChanged(); //make the Panel pull a fresh set of data from the DB
            target.add(listPanel);
        }
    });
```

This is an excerpt from the constructor of the Panel

```
public DBListPanel(String id, Model<String> selectionModel) {
    super(id);
    this.selectionModel = selectionModel;

    setOutputMarkupId(true);
    setRenderBodyOnly(false);

    ... //add contents
}
```

Comment: Can you show some context code that does the `target.add( panel)`?

Comment: @RobAu added relevant code. Hope this helps identifying the issue

Comment: I'm not sure about `selectionChanged()`. I assume it modified a `DataProvider` or something that puts data in a `DataTable`?

Comment: It does. `selectionChanged()` first pulls a `List` of data objects from the db, then checks whether it is empty to either set the visibility of the container that holds the table to false or updates the `DataProvider` with the updated list.